# How could I fix this problem: in_array () expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in file... on line

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with this code. 
I get warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in file... on line...

```
 /**
* Filter payment gateways
*/
function my_custom_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) {
$chosen_shipping_rates = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( ‘chosen_shipping_methods’ ) : array();

if ( in_array( ‘flexible_shipping_6_1’, $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
unset( $gateways[‘cod’] );

elseif ( in_array( ‘flexible_shipping_6_4’, $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
unset( $gateways[‘bacs’] );
unset( $gateways[‘paypal’] );

endif;
return $gateways;
}
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_available_payment_gateways’, ‘my_custom_available_payment_gateways’ );
```

It will be nice if somebody can help me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your code, it could be that the `$chosen_shipping_rates` array hasn't been initialized and is resolving to NULL.

For example, if you were to do `in_array('some string', $uninstantiated_array)`

This will return the warning you are receiving.

My guess is that this is happening because `WC()->session` is set, but not `WC()->session->get( ‘chosen_shipping_methods’ )` and thus you are getting a NULL array.

Try to see if adding a variable `$chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( ‘chosen_shipping_methods’ )` and then using `( isset( $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) ? $chosen_shipping_methods : array();` to see if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

according to your code and supposing that $chosen_shipping_rates is sometimes not an array you can avoid the issue by making sure to execute the responsible code only if the variable is an array:

```
/**
* Filter payment gateways
*/
function my_custom_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) {
    $chosen_shipping_rates = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( ‘chosen_shipping_methods’ ) : array();

    if(isset($chosen_shipping_rates) && is_array($chosen_shipping_rates )){
    if ( in_array( ‘flexible_shipping_6_1’, $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    unset( $gateways[‘cod’] );
    elseif ( in_array( ‘flexible_shipping_6_4’, $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    unset( $gateways[‘bacs’] );
    unset( $gateways[‘paypal’] );

    endif;
    }

return $gateways;
}

add_filter( ‘woocommerce_available_payment_gateways’, ‘my_custom_available_payment_gateways’ );
```